# gnuplot does not draw anything, just axics

Tags: gnuplot

I want to draw something transparent.
my script is :

```js
set output 'rcut.png'
set term png
set style fill transparent solid 0.2 noborder
set style circle radius 1
set multiplot layout 1,3 title "Error of the model"
set xlabel 'batch id'
set logscale xy
set format x "10^{\%T}"
set format y "10^{\%T}"
set key autotitle columnheader
#
set ylabel "Energy[eV]"
p 'rcut=3' u 1:4 w circles lc rgb "navy", 'rcut=6' u 1:4 w circles lc rgb "dark-pink"
#
set ylabel "Force[eV/{\305}]" 
p 'rcut=3' u 1:6 w circles lc rgb "navy", 'rcut=6' u 1:6 w circles lc rgb "dark-pink"
#
set ylabel
p 'rcut=3' u 1:8 w circles lc rgb "navy", 'rcut=6' u 1:8 w circles lc rgb "dark-pink"
#
unset multiplot
```

and it returns an empty plot file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzIEd.png)

but when i set the term emf, there will be data in the image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhywT.png)
but it is not what i want, the points are not transparent.

I really want to figure out why,thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Long answer**:
gnuplot can support two different png terminals, one based on the gd graphics library and selected by `set term png` and a second one based on the cairo graphics library and selected by `set term pngcairo`.   The gd version only supports transparency if you specify `set term png truecolor`, which creates an output png file with 24bits of RGB color per pixel and another 8 bits of transparency. Otherwise it generates png files that are smaller (8 bits per pixel) because they are limited to 256 colors and no transparency. The cairo version *always* produces files with 24bit RGB + 8bit transparency per pixel.

**Short answer**:
Use either `set term pngcairo` or `set term png truecolor`.